# Loop into a multidimensional array with PHP and echo datas

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pretty new in PHP and array.

I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [Africa] => Array
        (
            [City] => Algeria
        )

    [Asia] => Array
        (
            [Country] => China
        )

    [Europa] => Array
        (
            [City] => London
        )
)
```

How can I get something like:

```
- Africa : City is Algeria
- Asia : Country is China
- Europa : City is London
```

This is what I've tried:

```
foreach ($arr as $item => $val) {
    echo $item.' : '.$item[0].' is '.$val;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: A nested `foreach` may be easier as you don't always have `city` as the key.

Comment: `$item` is the *key* of your array (the continent string) so it makes no sense to access an offset on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47825387/2943403

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty basic example, so if you will only have one item under the continent:

```
foreach ($arr as $item => $val) {
    echo "$item : " . ($key = key($val)) . " is {$val[$key]}";
}
```

Or use `current()` or `reset()`:

```
echo "$item : " .  key($val) ." is " . reset($val);
```

Comment: `array_key_first` may be better if you are going to get only the first key of the array.

Comment: Doesn't matter if there is only one. `array_shift()` will do it too.